# Upload generated PDF to sharepoint list via InfoPath

Tags: infopath

i have an InfoPath 2007 file which includes code to generate a signed PDF out of the current infopath form. Now i want to upload this PDF via C# code into a sharepoint 2010 library.

I tried

```
            SPSite objSite = new SPSite(spSite);
            SPFolder objFolder = objSite.OpenWeb().GetFolder(spLibraryName);
            string sourcePath = document;


            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
            int fileSize = (int)fi.Length;
            SPFileCollection objFiles = objFolder.Files;
            byte[] myFile = new byte[fileSize];
            FileStream mystream = new System.IO.FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            mystream.Read(myFile, 0, fileSize);
            mystream.Close();
            string strFileUrl = document;
            SPFile spf = objFiles.Add(strFileUrl, myFile);
```

but it did not work because the SPSite could not be created /found.

Now i want to know if it is possible to use a dataConnection to put the PDF-file through.

How can i solve this?

thank you,
el

Answer (score 1):

Call EnsureParentFolder(SPWeb parentSite, string destinUrl) first, before you add the file to the collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587349%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: i'll give it a try. Previously i have to upgrade to Sharepoint 2010 standard edition because i am running SP Foundation :( I hope this will help me out too

Comment: nope, nothing helped :( I even can not create the SPWeb Object.. therefore the ensureParentFolder is not able to help

Comment: Are you sure your Uri for spSite is valid? Is the SPSite object being created successfully?

Comment: I can access the URI from IE and it works well. I dont know what i can do

Comment: OK, so let's backtrack a second here. In your post it says you can not create SPSite. Is this still true? Then you said you can not create SPWeb. Is this still true? Have you used the debugger to step line by line verifying the data you are passing? Finally, the value of strFileUrl should be the destination Url, not the source Url. Concatenate the destination folder Url, a \, and the desired filename. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms367739.aspx